# What are the scripting languages one should know to effectively use the Selenium tool for automation testing

Tags: testing, selenium

I am a fresher and being hired as a Quality Analyst in a software firm in automation testing
I have been told to study the Selenium tool.

Can you guys help me in knowing that what are the scripting languages I should get in touch so that I can effectively and efficiently use the tool to give the very best output of mine,

Hoping for responses....It would definitely help me a lot in going in proper direction....

Thanks in ADVANCE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly scripting languages, but be very fluent with **HTML** and **XML/XPath** to easily work with pages and understand how they work.

Knowing a little about JavaScript will also come in handy. As for other languages, Selenium natively speaks HTML, but you can write test cases in any of the following languages (list is not exhaustive):

- C#
- Java
- Perl
- PHP
- Python
- Ruby

Native HTML test case can be translated easily to the aforementioned languages, pick whichever you like the most.

Comment: The test case would be in HTML if you use the Selenium IDE. I recommend using it as a starting point but as you move on you need to shift to Selenium RC for more elegant programming. This requires you to know the basic Object Oriented Programming concepts

Answer (score 1):

You can get all these details from seleniumhq.org site. Please check the [documentation section](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/) . Also, regardless of the language you choose selenium features remain the same. So choose the language which you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what others have already said, to begin programming with your favorite language using Selenium RC, you need to be familiar with the basic **Object Orient Programming** concepts.

To help you with XPath there are tools like **XPather** and **Firebug** which automatically fetch you the XPath of the element.

Answer (score 0):

The perl language binding is quite reliable and up-to-date.

On the CPAN, the current release Test-WWW-Selenium-1.25     is from     28 Apr 2011. It's actively maintained.

Perl's Test Runners and TAP are cool. There are many other testing modules that you can combine with Test-WWW-Selenium.

Using E-P-I-C perl Editor for the Eclipse IDE, you'd get statement completion in your testcase files.

The Perl API calls are written in a slightly different naming convention: for instance, getEval becomes get_eval 
but this is a minor point.

IMHO, the perl code template that Selenium IDE generates for you is ok, it can be adapted. (e.g. I prefer Test::Fatal instead of Test::Exception.)

Cannot say anything about the other language bindings.

Choose the language you are most familiar with, and start building up your expert knowledge of testing tricks, Selenium and browser idiosyncrasies. this will take a lot of time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For any kind of strong automation, you should know atleast one scripting language like JavaScript, VBScript etc... and one full fledged programming language like Java, C# etc.. benefit of learning java or #C is ... you are comfortable in developing complex solutions because of their OOP nature and Java,C# are widely used in IT Industry.

Answer (score 0):

[Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org) is a robust scripting engine and reporting tool for automation testing.